# Retrieving data from url

Tags: url, python-3.x

Here is my function:

```
 from urllib import request

 my_url = 'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv'

 def download_data(a_url):
     a = request.urlopen(a_url)
     b = a.read()
     b = str(b)
     b = b. split("\n")
     c = open( "file_data" ,"w")
     for line in b:
         c.write(line)
     c.close()


 download_data(my_url)
```

After running it, I always get **this error**:

> [...]TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.

Is it a problem with my code? I've tried running it with different files already.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `requests` instead of `urllib`.

```
import requests

# same code up to...

a = requests.get(a_url)
```

Comment: I can only seem to find the requests module in the 2.7 or lower versions. Is it outdated?

Comment: I'm currently using it with 3.4.3 right now. Are you sure you're adding the 's' at the end in your script?

Comment: I've got the 3.4.1 version and there is no module named requests. Is it an addition in the newer versions of python?

Comment: For some reason I don't remember installing it. Go ahead and install through `pip install requests`. I'm sorry for the confusion.